# Android: Why can't I programmatically scroll this WebView?

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, scroll

I have a WebView that doesn't show an actual website, but gets fed HTML-formatted strings to display. I am requeired to scroll this WebView to the top on button press. I am aware there are a lot of similar questions on StackOverFlow, but none did help me - so I'm assuming my problem is different. I don't know much about HTML/CSS so maybe that's where the error comes from - not sure.

This is the code that feeds the content into my WebView:

```
fun wrapAndInflateHtml(webView: WebView, text: String) {
    val html = wrapWithHtml(webView.context, text)
    webView.loadData(html, "text/html", "UTF-8")
}

private fun wrapWithHtml(c: Context, htmlBody: String): String {
    return "<html>" + wrapCss(getCss(c)) +
            "<body>$htmlBody</body></html>"
}

private fun getCss(c: Context): String {
    return c.getString(R.string.html_header)
}

private fun wrapCss(css: String): String {
    return "<head><style>$css</style></head>"
}
```

This is the string resource for the header:

```
    <string name="html_header"><![CDATA[<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no\">
```

This is an example for a string that gets fed as the body (the `wrapAndInflateHtml`'s `text` argument):

```
<string name="imprint_html"><![CDATA[<p>Some Company<br />
Some Street 1<br />
City<br />
</p>
<p>Some more text here<br />
And a number: 65560<br />
</p>
<p>Some Text here:<br /><br />
Some more text.
</p>
<p>Phone: <a href=\"123456789\">123456789</a><br /><br />
Some more text<br /><a href=\"mailto:email@server.com\">email@server.com</a>.</p>]]></string>
```

This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/wv_imprint"
        style="@style/CopySmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_16" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and my fragment:

```
class HtmlViewerFragment : Fragment() {

    lateinit var title: String
    lateinit var html: String
    lateinit var webView: WebView

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
        extractArguments()
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_html_viewer, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        webView = wv_imprint
        wrapAndInflateHtml(wv_imprint, html)
    }

    private fun extractArguments() {
        arguments?.getString("title").let {
            title = it!!
        }
        arguments?.getString("html").let {
            html = it!!
        }
    }
}
```

Now if I add a method to programmatically scroll the WebView like this:
`hypotheticalButton.setOnClickListener { webView.scrollTo(0,0 }` it will have no effect. My WebView's scrollX and scrollY are always 0.

Does anyone have a hint as to how I can fix this?

Comment: what about wrapping webView tag inside ScrollView then call  `myScrollview?.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP)`

Comment: I tried that too, unfortunately it doesn't work. If I wrap it in a ScrollView the ScrollView's `scrollX`and `scrollY`will also always be 0 - yet I can manually scroll, if I have a very long HTML document, I can scroll for many screens, without these values ever changing.